# Zeros of polynomials with real exponents

Tags: complex-analysis

Does every non-constant function of the form 
\begin{equation*}
f(z)=a_0+a_1z^{r_1}+\ldots a_nz^{r_n} 
\end{equation*}
have a complex zero? Here the $r_k$ are positive reals, the $a_k$ are arbitrary complex numbers, and $a_kz^{r_k}$ is evaluated using the branch of the logarithm determined by $-\pi<\arg z\le\pi$.

Comment: Try to find a simple counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple counterexample is

$$f(z) = 1 + z^{1/2}.$$

The definition of $z^r$ used here implies that $\operatorname{Re} z^{1/2} \geqslant 0$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$, and therefore $\operatorname{Re} f(z) \geqslant 1$, which shows $f$ has no zero. Any exponent $0 < r < 1$ would give a zero-free function in the same manner.

Comment: Daniel, thank you, and I am truly surprised. It seems that any continuous branch of the logarithm function would give similar trouble.  I suppose that if you allow each log to be arbitrary then the statement is true.... Although now I'm not even confident about that.

Comment: I think there is a lesson here: Think geometrically!

Comment: The problem is that there is no global continuous branch of the logarithm. You always have discontinuities for non-integer exponents. If all exponents are $> 1$, then each non-constant term covers the whole plane (and at least parts of it several times), so functions $a + bz^r$ with $b\neq 0$ and $r \geqslant 1$ are surjective. If you have more than one term $a_k z^{r_k}$ ($r_k \geqslant 1$), I don't know whether you can combine them so that the function is not surjective, but as long as all your exponents are $< 1$, you can always avoid a sector.